# How to sequence animations in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animator

Like a play list with play,pause, next and back button I achieved it using if else in C# but like to use counter can some give me better idea.

public void nextSq()
    {

```
    if (CPU_Model.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Parent_1"))
    {

        CPU_Model.Play("Parent_2", -1, 0f);
        CPU_Model.speed = 0.25f;
    }

    else if (CPU_Model.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Parent_2"))
    {

        CPU_Model.Play("Parent_3", -1, 0f);
        CPU_Model.speed = 0.25f;
    }
    else if (CPU_Model.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Parent_3"))
    {

        CPU_Model.Play("Parent_4", -1, 0f);
        CPU_Model.speed = 0.25f;
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205043/discussion-on-question-by-udit-patel-how-to-sequence-animations-in-unity).

Comment: Hi man i am able to do the stuff but its messing my counter as i am using the same count to increment and decrement the states. thus wasting my one click and implementation is not funhctioining properly

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Animation view](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html), the [playable graphs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Playables-Graph.html) technology, or [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com) to sequence animations.